# search 1 column for a specific term, and when found copying the entire row into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search for a specific term in Column E of a document and when found copy the entire row that it is found in to another sheet in the same document. The below code is able to complete what i am trying to do, however it only does it for the first occurrence of the search and ends I need it to continue until all occurrences are found and copy and pasted. Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    'Start search in row 2 LSearchRow = 2
    'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable) LCopyToRow = 2
    While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
        'If value in column E = "Aries Radio Control", copy entire row to Sheet2
        If InStr(1, Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value, "Aries Radio Control") > 0 Then
            'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
            Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            'Paste row into Sheet ARC in next row
            Sheets("ARC").Select
            Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Move counter to next row
            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
            Sheets("sheet1").Select
        End If
        LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
    Wend
    'Position on cell A3 Application.CutCopyMode = False Range("A3").Select
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Exit Sub
    Err_Execute: MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to use a loop to achieve what you want. Example from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx#Anchor_2 follows.

```
This example finds all cells in the range A1:A500 on worksheet one that contain the value 2 and changes it to 5.

With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
    End If 
End With
```